# What is Content in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In the documentation, I see `Content` in a different context:

```
/// A modifier that can be applied to a view or other view modifier,
/// producing a different version of the original value.
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public protocol ViewModifier {
    /// The content view type passed to `body()`.
    typealias Content
}
```

and here

```
/// A view that arranges its children in a vertical line.
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public struct VStack<Content> where Content : View {
```

I can't find in the documentation the proper explanation of what does  `Content` mean. Is there any predefined `content` usage in SwiftUI?

Comment: Content is just a way to indicate a generic type, which in the case of SwiftUI usually represents any kind of view. To learn more about swift generics, check: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html

Answer (score 72):

It's important to understand that SwiftUI makes **heavy** use of generic types. Before the release of SwiftUI (and Combine), I had never seen any Swift code that makes such heavy use of generics. Almost all of the `View`-conforming types (and `ViewModifier`-conforming types) in SwiftUI are generic types.

### `ViewModifier`

So, first let's talk about `ViewModifier`. `ViewModifier` is a protocol. Other types can conform to `ViewModifier`, but no variable or value can just have the plain type `ViewModifier`.

To make a type conform to `ViewModifier`, we define a `body` method that takes a `Content` (whatever that is) and returns a `Body` (whatever that is):

```
func body(content: Content) -> Body
```

A `ViewModifier` is essentially just this one method, that takes a `Content` as input and returns a `Body` as output.

What's `Body`? `ViewModifier` defines it as an `associatedtype` with a constraint:

```
associatedtype Body : View
```

This means we get to pick the specific type known as `Body` in our `ViewModifier`, and we can pick any type for `Body` as long as it conforms to the `View` protocol.

And what is `Content`? The documentation tells you it's a `typealias`, which means we probably don't get to pick what it is. But the documentation doesn't tell you what `Content` is an alias of, so we don't know anything about what `body` can do with the `Content` it receives!

The reason the documentation doesn't tell you is because Xcode is programmed not to show you a public symbol from the SDK if the symbol begins with an underscore (`_`). But you can see the true definition of `ViewModifier`, including the hidden symbols, by looking in the `.swiftinterface` file for SwiftUI. I explain how to find that file in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56530199/77567).

Consulting that file, we find the true definition of `ViewModifier`:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public protocol ViewModifier {
  static func _makeView(modifier: SwiftUI._GraphValue<Self>, inputs: SwiftUI._ViewInputs, body: @escaping (SwiftUI._Graph, SwiftUI._ViewInputs) -> SwiftUI._ViewOutputs) -> SwiftUI._ViewOutputs
  static func _makeViewList(modifier: SwiftUI._GraphValue<Self>, inputs: SwiftUI._ViewListInputs, body: @escaping (SwiftUI._Graph, SwiftUI._ViewListInputs) -> SwiftUI._ViewListOutputs) -> SwiftUI._ViewListOutputs
  associatedtype Body : SwiftUI.View
  func body(content: Self.Content) -> Self.Body
  typealias Content = SwiftUI._ViewModifier_Content<Self>
}
```

There are also some extensions to `ViewModifier` that define defaults for `body`, `_makeView`, and `_makeViewList`, but we can ignore those.

So anyway, we can see that `Content` is an alias for `_ViewModifier_Content<Self>`, which is a `struct` that doesn't define any interesting public interface, but does (in an extension) conform to `View`. So this tells us that, when we write our own `ViewModifier`, our `body` method will receive some sort of `View` (the specific type is defined by the framework and we can just call it `Content`), and return some sort of `View` (we get to pick the specific return type).

So here's an example `ViewModifier` that we can apply to any `View`. It pads the modified view and gives it a colored background:

```
struct MyModifier: ViewModifier {
    var color: Color

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content.padding().background(color)
    }
}
```

Note that we don't have to name the type of `View` returned by `body`. We can use `some View` and let Swift deduce the specific type.

We can use it like this:

```
Text("Hello").modifier(MyModifier(color: .red))
```

### `VStack`

Now let's talk about `VStack`. The `VStack` type is a `struct`, not a protocol. It is generic, which means it takes type parameters (just like a function takes function parameters). `VStack` takes a single type parameter, named `Content`. This means `VStack` defines a **family** of types, one for every type it allows for `Content`.

Since `VStack`'s `Content` parameter is constrained to conform to `View`, this means that for every `View`-conforming type, there is a corresponding `VStack` type. For `Text` (which conforms to `View`), there is `VStack<Text>`. For `Image`, there is `VStack<Image>`. For `Color`, there is `VStack<Color>`.

But we don't normally spell out the full type instance of `VStack` we're using, and we don't usually have the `Content` type be a primitive like `Text` or `Image`. The whole reason to use a `VStack` is to arrange multiple views in a column. The use of `VStack` tells Swift to arrange its subviews vertically, and the `VStack`'s `Content` type parameter specifies the types of the subviews.

For example, when you write this:

```
VStack {
    Text("Hello")
    Button(action: {}) {
        Text("Tap Me!")
    }
}
```

you're actually creating an instance of this type:

```
VStack<TupleView<(Text, Button<Text>)>>
```

The `Content` type parameter here is the type `TupleView<(Text, Button<Text>)>`, which is itself a generic type `TupleView` with its own type parameter named `T`, and `T` here is `(Text, Button<Text>)` (a 2-tuple, also called a pair). So the `VStack` part of the type tells SwiftUI to arrange the subviews vertically, and the `TupleView<(Text, Button<Text>)>` part tells SwiftUI that there are two subviews: a `Text` and a `Button<Text>`.

You can see how even this short example generates a type with several levels of nested generic parameters. So we definitely want to let the compiler figure out these types for us. This is why Apple added the `some View` syntax to Swift—so we can let the compiler figure out the exact type.

Comment: Do you know how to extract the different tuple contents? How does apple do that for example with the SwiftUI Picker. They must somehow access the contents of the labels right?

Comment: That question is too involved to be just a comment on an answer.

Comment: There are quite a lot of words and no answer to the original question: What is the semantics of "Content"?
Say, in `TupleView<T>`, "T" could be "Content", but it isn't. While in `ViewBuilder` in `buildBlock<C0, C1>(_: _:)` "C0" stands for "Content0". And the is no clear demarcation line between "Content" and "Non-content".

Comment: The original question does not use the word “semantics” at all. Also, there is no “the” semantics because `Content` means different things in different contexts. I explained what `Content` means in the two concrete examples given in the question.

Comment: It would be great to add a final step where you declare `func padWithBackgroundColor` in a `extension View` so you can call `Text("Hello"). padWithBackgroundColor(.red)` directly.

Comment: @Rivera If you're asking for help doing that, please post a new question. I don't think it's appropriate for this question.

Comment: @robmayoff it was not a question, it was a suggestion to make your answer more complete. I could go ahead and edit it myself or post a different answer too.

Comment: Post your own answer if you want. Please don't edit mine.

Comment: @robmayoff Thanks a lot for this detailed explanation. For an experienced programmer who’s new to Swift, SwiftUI actually looks pretty strange on first sight, because it uses so many tricks to hide complexity from its users. Is that really a getter, is it a closure, and why can it have more than one return element. Still trying to figure out who exactly these Tuples are formed. If you’re not a dev, you might not even wonder. But as a dev coming from another language, this really makes your head spin around.

Answer (score 14):

This might also be helpful:

```
private struct FormItem<Content:View>: View {
    var label: String
    let viewBuilder: () -> Content
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
            Text(label).font(.headline)
            viewBuilder()
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it this way:

```
FormItem(label: "Your Name") {
    TextField("name", text: $bindingToName)
}
```

Because the `viewBinder` is the last property of the `struct`, you can place the contents after the `FormItem` function call.

Answer (score 8):

I love [Rob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56899716/788168), which answered *my* implicit question when I found this SO question, but I thought I could expand on Kontiki's comment, for programmers new to Swift or generics.

---

This question asks a couple things, specifically:

> What is Content in SwiftUI?

Surprisingly, **there is no actual `Content` class or struct or type in SwiftUI** (as far as I've seen)! Both examples in the question offer evidence of this.

What do I mean? `Content` is a *[generic](https://web.archive.org/web/20201029075437/https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html)*, kinda like a "variable that holds a type" (though I find that explanation confusing).

Generics are *really cool* (they're the reason that Swift & XCode autocomplete know that you put, say, strings in an array and not integers), but in this case the generic `Content` is simply being used to represent an arbitrary type that conforms to the `View` protocol (as in, a `Button` and *always* a `Button`, not `Text`). **The name `Content` is completely arbitrary**—Apple could equally have called it `Foo` or `MyView`, and if you're writing custom types that host their own content, you can choose whatever name you want.

If you've used languages that rely more on classes and subclasses (like Java or C++ or basically every other big, typed language), then it's fair to say, for comparison, that this generic is being used to require all "content" to adhere to the "base class" `View` (to be clear: `View` is not a class in SwiftUI; it is a protocol and behaves differently). Except—for a given instance of a control (for example, a specific `VStack`), `Content` must always be the same type. Once a `Button`, *always* a `Button`. This is why [sometimes you need to use `AnyView`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-return-different-view-types).

### All of this explained practically

How do I know all of this? The second example:

```swift
/// A view that arranges its children in a vertical line.
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public struct VStack<Content> where Content : View {
```

This code declares the struct `VStack`, which is a *generic type* because it corresponds to an *arbitrary struct/class/type* that the type's author chose to call `Content`. Not *any* arbitrary type, though, because `where Content : View` limits callers to using types that implement the `View` protocol.

Rob's answer explains the other example—that `Content` for a `ViewModifier` is just some sort of View as well (by examining other documentation).

Looking at the initializer for VStack, you'll see it takes a function that returns `Content`:

```swift
@inlinable public init(alignment: HorizontalAlignment = .center, spacing: CGFloat? = nil, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content)
```

When you create a VStack (or any other control with content), the content you provide is actually in that function—and from there, Swift can determine the concrete ("real") type of `Content` when it compiles:

```
VStack { // Function starts at `{`
    Text("test")
    Text("test 2")
} // Function ends at `}`
```

As Rob explains above, the concrete type in this function is actually some sort of `TupleView`. But because VStack is *generic* (and also limited to implementors of `View`), all it knows is that you've provided *some specific type* that implements `View`—and whatever type that is, we call it `Content`.

### Aside: `some View`

This also somewhat explains the usage of of `some View` in SwiftUI: though you *could* write out the full `TupleView` type every time you use it, if you added a Button at the end of your VStack, the function's type would change from `TupleView<(Text, Text)>` to `TupleView<(Text, Text, Button)>`, which is tedious to change everywhere it's needed. It's easier to say it's `some View` (as in, "this is a specific type that implements View and ignore everything else about it"). [And using `some View` is safer than using `View`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/why-does-swiftui-use-some-view-for-its-view-type):

> Returning `some View` has two important differences compared to just returning `View`:
>
> 1. We must always return the same type of view.
> 2. Even though we don’t know what view type is going back, the compiler does.

### Aside: multiple returns in a closure?

If you look at our VStack example again:

```swift
VStack { // Function starts at `{`
    Text("test")
    Text("test 2")
} // Function ends at `}`
```

You'll noticed that the function we use seems to have *2* return values (two `Text`s), using the **implicit return** syntax for [Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html). But notably, this implicit return only works for functions with one expression (the feature is called **Implicit Returns from Single-Expression Closures**!). For example:

```swift
func foo(n: Int) -> Int {
    n * 4
}
```

How can we return *two* things?

[How Well Do You Know SwiftUI?](https://blog.avenuecode.com/how-well-do-you-know-swiftui) describes it:

> But inside a **Trailing Closure**, it still wouldn’t be possible to put views one after another in a declarative way. If you notice in the HStack init method above, the last parameter that is a function of type `( ) -> Content` has a `@ViewBuilder` annotation. This is a new Swift 5.1 feature called **Function Builders**, which is what makes this syntax possible.

In short, the trailing closure used in `VStack` has the [`@ViewBuilder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder) annotation, which is a function builder ([Result Builder](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/deep-dive-into-swift-function-builders/)) that implicitly constructs `TupleView`s for your UI.

Comment: One thing I don't understand is for example in the `VStack` the argument `content: () -> Content` is a closure that returns a `Content` but when we initialize a `VStack` we don't return anything. In your example the `VStack`'s trailing closure just creates two `Text` views but does not return anything. How is that possible?

Comment: @mfshujaie, if I understand you correctly, this is just a continuation of Swift's **implicit returns from single-expression closures** ([Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html)), although I don't know how those two `Text` views get implicitly converted to a `TupleView` (which is what I assume is happening). I imagine that's your question, though :D

Comment: Yes, exactly that's my question how do those two `Text` views are converted to a single `TupleView`?

Comment: Found an answer here: https://blog.avenuecode.com/how-well-do-you-know-swiftui

Comment: Oh, really cool! `But inside a Trailing Closure, it still wouldn’t be possible to put views one after another in a declarative way. If you notice in the HStack init method above, the last parameter that is a function of type ( ) -> Content  has a @ViewBuilder annotation. This is a new Swift 5.1 feature called Function Builders, which is what makes this syntax possible`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: The concluding part of your  answer wonderfully  resolved the mystery of multiple returns in a closure. That was totally stumping me.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the function builders. I really struggled understanding why multiple return values were possible in a closure. To me, SwiftUI (and Swift) actually get pretty complex when trying to simplify things.