# SwiftUI: ViewModifier where content is an Image

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-protocols

I get an error "`Type 'PlayButtonModifier' does not conform to protocol 'ViewModifier'`" and I do not understand why and - even more important - how to do it right.

I simply try to create a `ViewModifier` for an `Image`, so that I can use for example `.resizable()` on it, which is only defined in `Image`

In the `ViewModifier` protocol, there's an `Typealias` for `Content` defined. My naiv thinking was that this should work:

```
struct PlayButtonModifier: ViewModifier {
    typealias Content = Image

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
    }
}
```

Well, no. Too easy. Same thing happens with implicit type alias for structs:

```
struct PlayButtonModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Image) -> some View {
        content
    }
}
```

Same error.

What is wrong here? How would it be correct?

Comment: Content is opaque typealias here... [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56833659/what-is-content-in-swiftui) will help you to clarify the area.

Comment: Hi @Asperi, the answer behind your link explains very well what happens behind the scenes. Thank you for this.
And now the 1 Mio $ question: How can I use it? Apple took all the effort, including even a syntax change in Swift, just to be able to modify standard plain views? Not even Images or Texts? I still believe, there's something in it, that I just have not uncovered, yet.

Comment: All modifiers actually a functions, ie. .resizable(). ViewModifier is generic mechanism for generic  View modification. For specific modifications you can create specific function, calculable property, dedicated View, etc. the only one requirement - those should generate some View as output.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In this case where the modification is specific to a particular view type, `Image` say, you could just add an extension on that view type directly:

```
extension Image {
    func myImageModifier() -> some View {
        self
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
            .clipShape(Circle())
   }
}
```

A full playground text example follows.  If you add a cute otter picture in your playground "Resources" folder named "Otter.png" you get a prettier result :)

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI

let image = (UIImage(named: "Otter.png") ?? UIImage(systemName: "exclamationmark.square")!)

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("hello world")
            Image(uiImage: image)
                .myImageModifier()
        }
    }
}

extension Image {
    func myImageModifier() -> some View {
        self
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
            .clipShape(Circle())
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
```

Answer (score 26):

thank's to the comments and discussion with [Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299030/asperi), I finally used the following code snippet. Basically, it's an implementation of `ViewModifier`, specialised for Images.

```
protocol ImageModifier {
    /// `Body` is derived from `View`
    associatedtype Body : View

    /// Modify an image by applying any modifications into `some View`
    func body(image: Image) -> Self.Body
}

extension Image {
    func modifier<M>(_ modifier: M) -> some View where M: ImageModifier {
        modifier.body(image: self)
    }
}
```

Using it is simple:

```
struct MyImageModifier: ImageModifier {
    func body(image: Image) -> some View {
        image.resizable().scaledToFit()
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "play").modifier(MyImageModifier())
    }
}
```

I'm not 100% satisfied, because the modifier must be defined either to return  `some View` or to return an `Image`. Both cases have disadvantages and do not perfectly integrate with SwiftUI.

When defining the `ImageModifier` to return an `Image` it reduces the possibilities of modifying the image to only the image-specific modifiers (actually `resizable()`) and when defining it to return `some View` I can't chain `ImageModifier`s as the second modifier must be a `ViewModifier`.

Comment: I'v been wanting to unravel this as well.

Comment: I was guessing it's better if return type is `Image` but not `some View`, so that we can chain the more Image functions.