# SwiftUI AsyncImage ProgressView deadline

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-asyncimage

How can I achieve such a scenario.

1. Using the AsyncImage I load the url.
2. Progress view turns around as placeholder
3. After 2 seconds we don't get an error
4. Our ProgressView changes to an image

This is a code:

```
AsyncImage(url: exampleURL) { phase in
    if let image = phase.image {
        image
            .imageModifier()
    } else if phase.error != nil {
        Image("example_image")
            .imageModifier()
    } else {
        ProgressView()
            .font(.largeTitle)
    }
}
```

There is any short and clean solution of I need to using custom implementation async image and using for example taskgroups? Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: You would have to create your own.

Comment: ok I go one that's pleases me. 
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58804696/swiftui-viewmodifier-where-content-is-an-image
2. asyncWithTimeout method from objc.io advanced swift 
and their connection. But too bad it's not on the library side.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach, using a `Timer` with `onReceive`, works well for me.
Set an appropriate `timeRemaining`. After that time has elapsed, the `AsyncImage`
will present the chosen image ("timer"), if the image is downloaded before that time, that image
will be displayed.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.trinum.com/ibox/ftpcam/mega_mtgenevre_sommet-des-gondrans.jpg")!

    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State var timeRemaining = 2
    
    var body: some View {
        AsyncImage(url: url) { phase in
            if timeRemaining <= 0 {
                Image(systemName: "timer")
            } else {
                switch phase {
                    case .empty: ProgressView()
                    case .success(let image):
                      image.resizable()
                        .onAppear { timer.upstream.connect().cancel() }
                    case .failure:
                      Image(systemName: "wifi.slash")
                        .onAppear { timer.upstream.connect().cancel() }
                    @unknown default: EmptyView()
                }
            }
        }
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
            if timeRemaining > 0 {
                timeRemaining -= 1
            } else {
                timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```