# Why does `ViewModifier` protocol has an `associatedtype` AND a `typealias`?

Tags: swiftui, swift-protocols, type-alias, associated-types

As far as I know, the definition of the [ViewModifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewmodifier) protocol looks like this:

```swift
protocol ViewModifier {

    // content view type passed to body()
    typealias Content

    // type of view returned by body()
    associatedtype Body : View

    // only requirement
   func body(content: Self.Content) -> Self.Body

}
```

My question is:

Why `Self.Content` is a `typealias` while `Self.Body` is an `associatedtype` ?
What's the difference?

Comment: `Body` will be inferred *from your* return, so it is associatedtype, `Content` will provided *to you*, it is known by ViewModifer (because generated by it), but hidden for you, so is typealias.

Answer (score 5):

> Why `Self.Content` is a `typealias` while `Self.Body` is an `associatedtype` ? What's the difference?

Because `Content` is a `typealias`, the author of the `ViewModifier` protocol gets to pick the type being aliased when she writes the protocol. (You can't see the type being aliased because that type is `_ViewModifier_Content<Self>`. When an identifier in the SDK starts with `_`, Apple omits the identifier from documentation and generated interfaces.)

Because `Body` is an `associatedtype`, **you** get to pick the type that it aliases, when you write a type that conforms to the `ViewModifier` protocol. You can make `Body` be any type you want, subject to two conditions:

- You must pick a type that conforms to `View` (because the `ViewModifier` protocol constrains `Body` to conform to `View`).
- You must be able to create or obtain an instance of whatever type you pick, because you have to return an instance of it from the `body` method. (Or you could crash or hang to avoid returning at all, but that's usually not what you want…)

So, when you implement a type conforming to `ViewModifier`, you cannot influence what `Content` means. It always means `_ViewModifier_Content<Self>`. But you can choose what `Body` means, by choosing the return type of the `body` method.

Here's I'll force `Body` to mean `EmptyView`:

```
struct EmptyModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> EmptyView {
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```

And here I'll force `Body` to mean `Color`:

```
struct RedModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> Color {
        Color.red
    }
}
```

Usually we use `some View` as the type, which means that Swift deduces the exact type for us and keeps it a secret:

```
struct FrameModifier: ViewModifier {
    var color: Color
    var width: CGFloat

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content
            .padding(width)
            .border(color, width: width)
    }
}
```

Here, all we know about the `Body` type is that it conforms to `View`. Swift tries pretty hard to keep us from finding out the real type at compile time.

Comment: The protocol fully defines a `typealias`, but only constrains the definition of an `associatedtype`. Each conformance then fully defines the `associatedtype` in its own way. This is the difference between a `typealias` and an `associatedtype`. My `EmptyModifier`, `RedModifier`, and `FrameModifier` examples are three different conformances. Each conformance defines `Body` differently. If `Body` were a `typealias`, it would have been fully defined by `ViewModifier` and my three conformances could not give it three different definitions.

Answer (score 0):

- `typealias` only changes the name of the type. Nothing more.
- `associatedtype` is a way to include *generics* in the protocol implementation.

---

```
public protocol ViewModifier {

    /// The type of view representing the body of `Self`.
    associatedtype Body : View

    /// Returns the current body of `self`. `content` is a proxy for
    /// the view that will have the modifier represented by `Self`
    /// applied to it.
    func body(content: Self.Content) -> Self.Body

    /// The content view type passed to `body()`.
    typealias Content
}
```

In the above example `Body` is a concrete type conforming to `View` and is inferred by the `body(content:)` return type.

`Content` is just another name for a type passed as the `content` parameter.

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56899716/8697793) by rob mayoff explained the `ViewModifier` in a more detailed way:

> So this tells us that, when we write our own `ViewModifier`, our `body`
> method will receive some sort of `View` (the specific type is defined by
> the framework and we can just call it `Content`), and return some sort
> of `View` (we get to pick the specific return type).

This means you don't know what the `Content` is, you just operate on it - it's called `Content` for your convenience, so you don't have to deal with `_ViewModifier_Content<Self>`.

Comment: _associatedtype is a way to include generics in the protocol implementation_ It's merely a way to include another type class/protocol. e.g. you can also use a `UIView` which isn't a protocol...