# How does the VStack gets the View elements inside the closure?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm pretty new to swift and swiftUi, and I wonder how does the VStack (or Hstack, ZStack, etc...) captures the View elements inside the closure?

For example, how does the VStack knows and gets the two `Text` elements even tho the closure doesn't return anything?

```swift
       VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
        }
```

Also, I wander if I can mimic this behavior and implement a struct that does the same?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56833659/what-is-content-in-swiftui ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closure passed to VStack is a special kind of closure marked with `@ViewBuilder`

A ViewBuilder is a custom parameter attribute that constructs View from closures. You can create your own ViewBuilders as shown in the example of the [ViewBuilder documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder).