# Passing View as a view modifier content to a function parameter

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am creating a reusable bottom up panel where the view displayed inside the bottom up panel will be different. I also wanted this panel to be a view modifier. I have created view modifiers in past, but hasn't passed view as a view modifier content ever. When I try to pass the view, I am getting an error described below.

***View modified code:***

```
struct BottomPanel: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    let panelContent: Content

    init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder panelContent: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.panelContent = panelContent()
        self._isPresented = isPresented
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.overlay(self.$isPresented.wrappedValue ? bottomPanelContent() : nil)
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    private func bottomPanelContent() -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                self.panelContent
            }
            // some modifiers to change the color or height of the panel.
        }
    }
}
```

***View extension:***

```
extension View {
    func bottomPanel(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder panelContent: @escaping () -> BottomPanel.Content) -> some View {
        return modifier(BottomPanel(isPresented: isPresented, panelContent: panelContent)
    }
}
```

***Content view and child view that I wish to open in bottom up panel:***

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showBottomPanel: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: { self.showBottomPanel = true}) {
                Text("Click me to open bottom panel")
            }
        }
        .bottomPanel(isPresented: $self.showBottomPanel, panelContent: { ChildView() })
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Click Me 1", action: {}).foregroundColor(.blue)
            Button("Click Me 2", action: {}).foregroundColor(.red)
        }
    }
}
```

Error: `Cannot convert value of type 'ChildView' to closure result type 'BottomPanel.Content' (aka '_ViewModifier_Content<BottomPanel>')`.

What am I doing wrong? How do I pass the view to BottomPanel?

Note: I have removed a lot of code from bottom panel to keep the code post short, but let me know if it's needed and I can share.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2):

You wrote this:

> ```
>     let panelContent: Content
> ```

The problem is that [`Content` here is a special type defined by SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56833659/what-is-content-in-swiftui/56899716#56899716). It's a type-erased container kind of like `AnyView`, except that you cannot create your own values of this `Content` type.

You need to introduce your own generic type parameter for the panel content. You should also store the `ViewBuilder` callback that creates the panel content rather than computing it even when the panel isn't shown.

```
struct BottomPanel<PanelContent: View>: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    let panelContent: () -> PanelContent

    init(
        isPresented: Binding<Bool>,
        panelContent: @escaping () -> PanelContent
    ) {
        self.panelContent = panelContent
        self._isPresented = isPresented
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.overlay(self.$isPresented.wrappedValue ? bottomPanelContent() : nil)
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    private func bottomPanelContent() -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                panelContent()
            }
            // some modifiers to change the color or height of the panel.
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to update your `bottomPanel` modifier to also be generic. In this case you can use the opaque parameter syntax instead of adding an explicit `PanelContent` generic parameter:

```
extension View {
    func bottomPanel(
        isPresented: Binding<Bool>,
        @ViewBuilder panelContent: @escaping () -> some View
    ) -> some View {
        return modifier(BottomPanel(isPresented: isPresented, panelContent: panelContent))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the content to present by making a handful of changes. Without knowing *how* the content is meant to look, I cannot definitively say whether or not this actually presents the content as desired - **but it presents the content nonetheless, circumventing the error that you were trying to bypass**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ContentViewTest: View {
    @State var showBottomPanel: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: { self.showBottomPanel = true}) {
                Text("Click me to open bottom panel")
            }
        }
        .bottomPanel(isPresented: $showBottomPanel, panelContent: { AnyView(ChildView()) }())
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Click Me 1", action: {}).foregroundColor(.blue)
            Button("Click Me 2", action: {}).foregroundColor(.red)
        }
    }
}



extension View {
    func bottomPanel(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, panelContent: AnyView) -> some View {
        return modifier(BottomPanel(isPresented: isPresented, panelContent: AnyView(panelContent)))
    }
}


struct BottomPanel: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    let panelContent: AnyView
    
    init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, panelContent: AnyView) {
        self.panelContent = AnyView(panelContent)
        self._isPresented = isPresented
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.overlay(self.$isPresented.wrappedValue ? bottomPanelContent() : nil)
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    private func bottomPanelContent() -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                self.panelContent
            }
            // some modifiers to change the color or height of the panel.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: panelContent won't always be of type ChildView. I am trying to create BottomPanel as reusable component, so panelContent can be ChildView, it can be SummaryView or any other custom view. I just want to pass different views to bottom panel and that will be displayed.

Comment: @tech_human Ah, I see. I've edited the answer to accept a view of any type, not just `ChildView`. Is the edit more along the lines of what you are looking for?