# Timeline reload policy seems to be ignored in WidgetKit

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit

In the following example, I create 4 timeline entries in one-second intervals, specifying the timeline reload policy `.atEnd`.

```
func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
    let currentDate = Date()
    var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []

    for secondOffset in 0...3 {
        let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: secondOffset, to: currentDate)!
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, configuration: configuration)

        entries.append(entry)
    }

    completion(Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd))
}
```

The widget view will show the second of the timeline entry's date, just to make it visible to the user that the widget has been updated.

```
struct MyWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(Calendar.current.component(.second, from: entry.date))")
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I run this on the simulator or an actual iPhone, the widget will count up 4 times, e.g. showing "17", "18", "19", "20". After that, it'll stop updating.

I expected WidgetKit to request a new timeline at this point, since the timeline reload policy `.atEnd` has been specified.

I'm aware that in this case the date of the last entry only signifies the *earliest date* for a new timeline to be requested, but it seems that a new timeline will never be requested, even after minutes of waiting or locking/unlocking the phone etc.

I have found [this possibly related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66262971/widgetkit-timeline-doesnt-update-entries), but my example seems to be even simpler, so I think it might be worth asking.

Am I misunderstanding how the timeline policy works?

Comment: You can't create an entry every 1 second - the interval is too short. Try longer intervals like 5 minutes.

Comment: @pawello2222 I was afraid that might become a problem - so there's no way to implement a timer widget that's precise down to the second?

Comment: No, at least officially - this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66408154/8697793